# Add a class to a selectbox in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, drop-down-menu

I cannot figure out how to add a class to this select box in Rails 3.

```
<%= select(:item, :item_type, [['Phone', 1], ['Email', 2], ['Website', 3], ['Address', 4], ['Occupation', 5]]) %>
```

Is there anyone that knows how to do it?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's the official documentation for the [select helper](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormOptionsHelper.html#method-i-select)

```
<%= select(:item, :item_type, [['Phone', 1], ['Email', 2], ['Website', 3], ['Address', 4], ['Occupation', 5]], {}, :class => "myclass") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameters for select are the object, attribute, select list, a hash of method options, and a hash of html options, which have to be separate.  If you want a 'toast' class, this works:

```
<%= select(:item, :item_type, [['Phone', 1], ['Email', 2], ['Website', 3], ['Address', 4], ['Occupation', 5]], {}, {:class => 'toast'}) %>
```

Note the empty hash - this needs to be here so that the method knows the *following* hash is for html options, which it passes directly onto the tag.